# Package pyhwm14 errors out on import statement

Tags: python, model, fortran, f2py

I need the Horizontal wind model for my bachelor thesis, for which i need the aerodynamic velocity of a spacecraft. I checked for multiple wind models which provide wind velocity in the upper atmosphere, and the best one was indeed hwm, which source is written in Fortran90.

Luckily, there is a python wrapper package called pyhwm14. The installation using pip goes fine. But when i come to use the package as follows:

```
from pyhwm2014.pyhwm14 import HWM14, HWM14Plot
```

the following error pops.

```
 File "C:\-\lib\site-packages\pyhwm2014\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import hwm14
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing hwm14: The module could not be found.
```

To resolve the error i tried to look in the package folder directory and have the following picture for the files:

1. .libs
2. _*pycache*_
3. _*init*_.py
4. hwm14.cp310-win_amd64.pyd

I assumed the file hwm14  that needs to be imported in the **_*init*_**.py can only be the hwm14.cp310-win_amd64.pyd file, which exists in the directory, but why is Python not finding it and not running?

Resolve the import error or find other package with no issues like this.

Ofcourse if someone has experience with wrappers and can teach me how to use the source f90 code in python, this also would be greate.

Thank you everyone

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Did you actually compile the Fortran code to get the dll? You cannot just use Fortran code in Python, you have to compile the Fortran code to a library and use the library.

Comment: hwm14 is a *DLL* file that is compiled during pip install (since the project does not provide wheel) -- If the dll is not compiled as part of the installation and you are not seeing any issues, its a bug in the project. If you happen to have fortran compiler, compilation flags are @ https://github.com/rilma/pyHWM14/blob/master/setup.py#L12

Comment: If it is in the current directory put a dot in front of pyhwm2014

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Install mingw64 ([x86_64-8.1.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0](https://github.com/2641797006/c/blob/master/GCC-zip/x86_64-8.1.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0.7z) worked for me)
2. Add bin folder of mingw64 to the PATH
3. Go to the project root folder
4. Run installation from the source code from https://github.com/rilma/pyHWM14

```bash
    git clone https://github.com/rilma/pyHWM14.git
    cd pyHWM14
    pip -q install coveralls 
    pip install numpy 
    pip install -e .
```

5. Find .dll file in \pyHWM14\pyhwm2014.libs, copy it to the upper level
6. Copy the contents of the \pyHWM14\data (two .dat and one .bin files should be there) to the C:\ (or whatever your root directory is)
7. `coverage run tests/test.py -v`

Comment: Thank you for answering. After "pip install -e .".

python setup.py develop did not run successfully.

 C:\HWM14\pyHWM14\setup.py:6: DeprecationWarning:
      `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
      of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
      Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
      It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.

Is there no a turn arround since im obliged to use the new python versions, because everything else in the model is depending on it?